# golang how to test if one exported function calls another unexported

Tags: go

What is the best way to test if one exported `func` calls another? E.g. (bit of a contrived example):

```
type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) DoSomethingA(param string) bool {
    return f.doSomethingParams(param, false, true)
}
func (f *Foo) DoSomethingB(param string) bool {
    return f.doSomethingParams(param, true, true)
}
func (f *Foo) DoSomethingC(param string) bool {
    return f.doSomethingParams(param, false, false)
}
func (f *Foo) doSomethingParams(param string, optA, optB bool) bool {
    // do stuff here
}
```

I can test `doSomethingParams()` independently in all its variants. I want a simple test that when I call `DoSomethingA()` that it calls `doSomethingParams(param, false, false)`, etc.

What is the easiest way to do that? Obviously replacing `Foo` with an interface won't work as this is a specific implementation I am testing which, in turn, is calling its own implementation of `doSomethingParams()`.

Comment: Are you looking for a runtime test, or a static analysis test, or something else?

Comment: Standard unit testing.

Comment: One approach is to change `doSomethingParams` from a method into a field of type func, after that you could mock it during a test. You may have to change it's signature to add `*Foo` as a param if it depends on the receiver. One downside of this, at least for me, is that `*Foo` can't be compared with `reflect.DeepEqual` reliably anymore.

Comment: @mkopriva that is an interesting approach, probably would work, but does "feel" like it is wrong (anti-pattern). It shouldn't be all that hard to just stub it out, should it?

Comment: Oh, I might be able to use embedding? Not sure...

Comment: @deitch If it's a function/method it is. The "right" way would be to introduce an interface, have that as a field on `Foo` and have `DoSomethingX` call the interface method instead. This way, then, you can rely on `reflect.DeepEqual` but it may feel like overkill to create interfaces for this.

Comment: *"It shouldn't be all that hard to just stub it out, should it?"* @deitch, you cannot stub the method `Foo.doSomethingParams`, it's not possible in Go. To give `Foo` access to a stub/mock/fake, it has to be a parameter (of type interface or func) to a method call or a field (of type interface or func) of `Foo`.

Comment: @mkopriva _ The "right" way would be to introduce an interface_ yes, but if it is within the same struct....

Comment: @deitch well you can always rethink the design of the actual test. For example you could have your exported methods reuse the test table you use to test the unexported method.

Comment: "reuse the test table" - yeah, not a bad idea. A bit wasteful to rerun everything, but in the context of go, which is very quick, not too bad.

Comment: Nah, embedding didn't work. How would I use an interface in the same struct (above example)?

Comment: I don't think that's a useful test. It's certainly not a _unit_ test. What you should be testing for is that the function has the proper return values and/or proper side effects.  If a future implementation accomplishes that goal without calling `doSomethingParams()`, the test should continue to pass.

Comment: Actually, given that `DoSomethingA` is exported, your approach is correct, methinks.

Comment: Generally I agree with @Flimzy, but if you have an exported method that passes args specific to it to an unexported one and the computation of the unexported one is expensive. It may make sense to just test that the exported passes the correct values to the unexported one.

Comment: the point @mkopriva is making is roughly where I was.

Comment: So did you get to a conclusive answer on this? I'm struggling with the same thing. It feels like I am kind of bloating my tests now by rewriting the logic that tests what `doSomethingParams` does inside all my tests for the exported functions. I am basically writing the exact same test for `doSomethingParams` inside `DoSomethingA`, `B` and `C`. Would be nicer to say "just assume that `doSomethingParams` has been called", and then test `doSomethingParams` only once. Else if functions `D` through `Z` are added, the test will be humongous.

Comment: Not really, or at least nothing beyond the suggestions in the comments. It just isn't something built into go. Use an interface (overkill) or accept it.